# simulink model in matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am working on detecting road lanes using hough transform in simulink(matlab). I have designed the model but its not detecting the lanes. As i am very new to simulink so i have no idea where i am doing the mistake. I tried to upload the model but its not working. I have used the same model as given in matlab-simulink demo except i added a new block of rgb2intensity just after the image from file block and the image which i have given as an input is also uploaded[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgJqK.jpg).Any help???

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing a screenshot of your actual model, it's difficult to give specific detail, but here is some general advice that you may find helpful.

I would debug a Simulink model pretty much the same way that I would debug any other piece of code -- by trying to understand exactly what *is* happening in my model by examining the output at each step.

For starters, I would make use of the [To Workspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/toworkspace.html) block, to see what the data actually looks like at the intermediate stages of your model.  This will help you to identify *where* things are going wrong.  For example, what is the output of rgb2intensity?  Is this function transforming your data in the way that you expect it to?  Ask that question of each block in your model if you have to.  If the block is not behaving the way that you expect it to, then you can ask *why*?

Another tool that might be useful for you is the [Simulink Debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/f5-6104.html).

Comment: I have uploaded the model along with the image which I have used as an input at: http://www.filefactory.com/file/1vepljtmbivt/n/road_jpg http://www.filefactory.com/file/396nlmzeg15b/n/model_jpg                                             I want to confirm one thing more that would I be able to detect lanes with this model?